# Convert HTML to Plain Text while preserving P, BR, UL, OL?

Tags: c#, html, string, html-parsing

During exporting from an HTML text to an Excel sheet, I'm trying to preserve basic formattings like HTML line breaks (`<br>`, `<p>`), lists (`<ol>`, `<ul>`) etc.

*Example input:*

```
<p>This is a test.</p>
<p>This is another<br>test.</p>

<ul>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>30</li>
</ul>

<p>End.</p>
```

*Example output:*

```
This is a test.

This is another
test.

- 10
- 20
- 30

End.
```

The free utility [HTMLAsText](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/htmlastext.html) from the famous NirSoft guy seems to do just what I want, unfortunately it comes with no source code:

[image]

Even after examining the approx. 20 similar questions here on Stack Overflow and browsing Google for hours, the closest thing I could find is [this Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/HTML_to_Plain_Text.aspx).

**My question therefore is:**

Is anyone aware of a class/library that could convert HTML to Plain Text while preserving basic formattings?

**Update 2013-05-10**

I ended up with one function, [see the full code over at Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NswerNkQ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not do this yourself by replacing:

```
<br /> with Environment.NewLine
</p> with Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine
<li> with " - ".
```

Then just strip out the rest of the HTML with regex? It would seem to achieve what you want your example output to be. Of course, someone may have a more elegant solution that that. =)

Comment: Thanks, @Jon, I'm doing something similar now!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using [this one](http://patapage.com/applications/pataPage/site/test/HtmlSanitizer.cs) and just setting the 'allowed tags' to the ones you want?

Comment: Thanks, @Paul. Actually I do _not_ want to allow any HTML tags, but I rather want to have the Plain HTML with all HTML tags removed and replaced the good ones with their Plain Text equivalent. I'm updating my question.

Comment: plus 1, i wound up on this page looking for this, sanitizer was what i needed.